# NLog Inner Exception Logging

Tags: logging, nlog, exception-logging

I'm trying to log inner exception messages by using NLog. This is a piece of my ***NLog.config*** file:

```xml
<target name="errors" xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate}${newline}
    - Exception Message: ${exception:format=Message}${newline}
    - InnerException Message: ${exception:innerExceptionSeparator=TEXT}${newline}"
   fileName="\Logs\errors-${shortdate}.log"
   concurrentWrites="true" />
</targets>
```

I'm getting the same message `See the inner exception for details`for both `Exception Message` and `InnerException Message` lines of ***NLog.config*** file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This worked for me:

```xml
  <target name="errors" xsi:type="File" layout="
            ${message}
            ${onexception:EXCEPTION OCCURRED\:
            ${exception:format=type,message,method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method}}"
            fileName="\Logs\errors-${shortdate}.log"
            concurrentWrites="true"
            />
  </targets>
```

Property descriptions :

- `${exception:maxInnerExceptionLevel=N}` - controls how many inner exceptions are logged. defaults to zero for backwards compatibility.
- `${exception:innerExceptionSeparator=TEXT}` - defines text that separates inner exceptions. Defaults to new line string (platform specific).
- `${exception:innerFormat=FORMATSTRING}` - defines the format of inner exceptions the same way that `${exception:format=FORMATSTRING}` defines the format of the top-level exception. If this parameter is not specified, the same format is used for both top-level and inner exceptions.

Here is the official [Nlog Documentation](https://nlog-project.org/2011/04/20/exception-logging-enhancements.html) for logging inner exceptions

Comment: layout in several lines causes log messages to be started not from the leftmost position in console window, the same is for file. Spaces (tabs) between `${message}` and line start are shown in the log

Answer (score 7):

another possibility is to add new line between inner exception is to use linebreak `&#xD;&#xA` in the xml, since `innerExceptionSeparator` is not parsed in some special way and is loaded as it is written. So `innerExceptionSeparator=${newline}` will not work.

```
layout="${message}${onexception:${newline}${exception:maxInnerExceptionLevel=10:innerExceptionSeparator=&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;:format=shortType,message}}
```

this will cause inner exception text to be started from the new line and indented by tab character

however this works only if `ILogger.Error(Exception, string)` method is used.
`ILogger.Error(Exception)` ignores this layout