# Loggly and Inner Exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, nlog, loggly

I am using loggly with NLog in C#.

When I use, for example, the following code.

```
protected static readonly NLog.Logger _log = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();                      

try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _log.Error(ex, "UpdateBrokerData {Account}", accountBalanceDto.Account);
}
```

The exception message is displayed but none of the inner exceptions.

Is there a way to get this to happen (perhaps with a setting in the NLog.config?

Here is the loggly part of my NLog.config file.

```
<target name="Loggly" xsi: type="Loggly">
  <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" excludeProperties="">
    <attribute name="environment" layout="${environment:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}" />
    <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
    <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
    <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
  </layout>
</target>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NLog Inner Exception Loggin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287491/nlog-inner-exception-loggin)

Comment: Maybe... but the loggly stuff seems separate... but I'll try it and see if it actually does change things.

Comment: I don't think so... because in that answer it has type file and filename... which wouldn't apply for loggly... my question is how to get this same functionality with NLog and loggly.

Comment: Looking at the code of a random NLog Loggly Target. Then it looks like the Exception-object is just added to the Data-collection and is then JsonSerialized. https://github.com/neutmute/nlog-targets-loggly/blob/966c4b11f5c198dfd2a0b43434b19932dda659f6/src/NLog.Targets.Loggly/LogglyTarget.cs#L275 and https://github.com/neutmute/loggly-csharp/blob/a7518a2ed734b2f820b47340059cf1f1dbebaf30/source/Loggly/LogglyClient.cs#L74